# How do I automatically deliver the SQL Server built in reports?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

When you right click on a number of items in the object explorer, it gives you the option for a reports menu. Various reports may exist depending on which type of item is selected. Yet, there does not appear to be any built-in functionality for automated delivery of these reports. It is hidden away somewhere?

My real question : Is there any way to set some of these up to be automatically delivered through email? The reports I am targeting are the "Job Steps Execution History", and "Top Jobs" reports for SQL Server agent. I am using SQL Server 2005/2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no scheduling capability in SSMS for the SSMS reports. This is by design, if the limitations [stated here apply to standard reports too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/managingsql/custom-reports-in-management-studio) (SQL Server Manageability Team Blog)

However, (I haven't tried this) the reports are available to use in a full SSRS install. See another page ["on the same blog as above"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/managingsql/management-studio-reports-part-3-standard-reports), attached zip file

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a really easy way to do this without installing SSRS or any other tools.  I used SQL Profiler, ran the reports stated, and got the code which I copied below.  You will want this copied in a scheduled job and have it send out the mail from within the job and you're done!

**This is the query passed for the 'jobs history' report:**

```
exec sp_executesql @stmt=N'begin try
use msdb; 
Select (dense_rank() over(order by s1.job_id))%2 as l1
,       (dense_rank() over(order by s1.job_id,s2.step_id))%2 as l2
,       s1.job_id as [Job Id]
,       s1.name as [Job Name]
,       s2.step_id as [Step Id]
,       s2.step_name as [Step Name]
,       case when ( Select count(*) from sysjobhistory s3 where ( s2.job_id = s3.job_id and s2.step_id = s3.step_id  and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert(varchar,s3.run_date)), getdate() ) < 7  ) ) is null 
                 then 0.0 
                 else ( Select count(*) from sysjobhistory s3 where ( s2.job_id = s3.job_id and s2.step_id = s3.step_id  and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert(varchar,s3.run_date)), getdate() ) < 7  ) ) 
        end as [Total Executions]
,       Case when ( Select count(*) from sysjobhistory s3 where ( s2.job_id = s3.job_id  and s2.step_id = s3.step_id  and s3.run_status = 0  and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert(varchar,s3.run_date)), getdate() ) < 7  ) ) is null
                then 0.0
                else ( Select count(*) from sysjobhistory s3 where ( s2.job_id = s3.job_id  and s2.step_id = s3.step_id  and s3.run_status = 0  and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert(varchar,s3.run_date)), getdate() ) < 7  ) ) 
        end as [Failed Executions]
,       case when ( Select avg(((run_duration/10000*3600) + ((run_duration%10000)/100*60) + (run_duration%100))) from sysjobhistory s3 where ( s2.job_id = s3.job_id and s2.step_id = s3.step_id and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert(varchar,s3.run_date)), getdate() ) < 7  ) ) is NULL 
                then 0.0 
                else ( Select avg((((run_duration)/10000*3600) + ((run_duration%10000)/100*60) + (run_duration%100))) from sysjobhistory s3 where ( s2.job_id = s3.job_id and s2.step_id = s3.step_id and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert(varchar,s3.run_date)), getdate() ) < 7  ) ) 
        end as [Average Run Duration]
,       case when (Select avg(retries_attempted+0.0) from sysjobhistory s3 where ( s2.job_id = s3.job_id and s2.step_id = s3.step_id  and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert(varchar,s3.run_date)), getdate() ) < 7  ) ) is null 
                then 0.0 
                else (Select avg(retries_attempted+0.0) from sysjobhistory s3 where ( s2.job_id = s3.job_id and s2.step_id = s3.step_id and run_status <> 2 and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert(varchar,s3.run_date)), getdate() ) < 7  ) ) 
        end  as [Average Retries Attempted] 
from sysjobs s1 
inner join sysjobsteps s2 on ( s1.job_id = s2.job_id ) 
order by s1.job_id, s2.step_id
end try
begin catch
select -100 as l1
,       1 as l2,        1 as [Job Id],  1 as [Job Name],1 as [Step Id],1 as [Step Name]
,       ERROR_NUMBER() as [Total Executions]
,       ERROR_SEVERITY() as [Failed Executions]
,       ERROR_STATE() as [Average Run Duration]
,       ERROR_MESSAGE() as [Average Retries Attempted]
end catch',@params=N''
```

**This is the query for 'top jobs: 20 most frequently failing jobs'**

```
exec sp_executesql @stmt=N'begin try
use msdb;
Select top  20 sj.job_id as [Job ID]
,       sj.name as [Job Name]
,       sl.name as [Owner Name]
,       jh.run_status
,       (Select count(*) from sysjobschedules js1 where js1.job_id = sj.job_id ) as [Schedules Count]
,       (Select count(*) from sysjobsteps js2 where js2.job_id = sj.job_id ) as [Steps Count]
,       (Select count(*) from sysjobhistory jh1 where jh1.job_id=sj.job_id and jh1.step_id = 0 and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert( varchar, jh1.run_date) ), getdate()) < 7  ) as [Execution Count]
,       (Select avg(((run_duration/10000*3600) + ((run_duration%10000)/100*60) + (run_duration%100))+0.0) from sysjobhistory jh2 where jh2.job_id=sj.job_id and jh2.step_id = 0 and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert( varchar, jh2.run_date) ), getdate()) < 7  ) as [Average Run Duration]
,       (Select avg(retries_attempted+0.0) from sysjobhistory jh2 where jh2.job_id=sj.job_id and jh2.step_id = 0 and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert( varchar, jh2.run_date) ), getdate()) < 7  ) as [Average  Retries Attempted]
,       Count(*) as [Failure Count]
,    1 as l1 
from sysjobhistory jh
inner join sysjobs sj on ( jh.job_id = sj.job_id )
inner join sys.syslogins sl on ( sl.sid = sj.owner_sid )
where jh.step_id = 0 and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert( varchar, jh.run_date) ), getdate()) < 7 and jh.run_status = 0 
group by sj.job_id, sj.name, sl.name, jh.run_status  
order by [Failure Count] desc
end try
begin catch
select 1 as [Job ID],1 as [Job Name],1 as [Owner Name],1 as run_status,1 as [Schedules Count],1 as [Steps Count]
,       ERROR_NUMBER() as  [Execution Count]
,       ERROR_SEVERITY() as [Average Run Duration]
,       ERROR_STATE() as [Average  Retries Attempted]
,       ERROR_MESSAGE() as [Failure Count]
,       -100 as l1 
end catch',@params=N''
```

**This is the query for '20 most frequently ran jobs':**

```
exec sp_executesql @stmt=N'begin try
use msdb;
Select top 20 sj.job_id as [Job ID]
,       sj.name as [Job Name]
,       sl.name as [Owner Name]
,       (Select count(*) from sysjobschedules js1 where js1.job_id = sj.job_id ) as [Schedules Count]
,       (Select count(*) from sysjobsteps js2 where js2.job_id = sj.job_id ) as [Steps Count]
,       (Select count(*) from sysjobhistory jh1 where jh1.job_id=sj.job_id and jh1.step_id = 0 and jh1.run_status = 0 and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert( varchar, jh1.run_date) ), getdate()) < 7  ) as [Failure Count]
,       (Select avg(((run_duration/10000*3600) + ((run_duration%10000)/100*60) + (run_duration%100))+0.0) from sysjobhistory jh2 where jh2.job_id=sj.job_id and jh2.step_id = 0 and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert( varchar, jh2.run_date) ), getdate()) < 7  ) as [Average Run Duration]
,       (Select avg(retries_attempted+0.0) from sysjobhistory jh2 where jh2.job_id=sj.job_id and jh2.step_id = 0 and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert( varchar, jh2.run_date) ), getdate()) < 7  ) as [Average  Retries Attempted]
,       Count(*) as [Execution Count]
, 1 as l1
from sysjobhistory jh
inner join sysjobs sj on ( jh.job_id = sj.job_id )
inner join sys.syslogins sl on ( sl.sid = sj.owner_sid )
where jh.step_id = 0 and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert( varchar, jh.run_date) ), getdate()) < 7 
group by sj.job_id, sj.name, sl.name
order by [Execution Count] desc
end try
begin catch
select 1 as [Job ID],1 as [Job Name],1 as [Owner Name],1 as run_status,1 as [Schedules Count],1 as [Steps Count]
,       ERROR_NUMBER() as  [Execution Count]
,       ERROR_SEVERITY() as [Average Run Duration]
,       ERROR_STATE() as [Average  Retries Attempted]
,       ERROR_MESSAGE() as [Failure Count]
,       -100 as l1 
end catch',@params=N''
```

**20 slowest jobs**:

```
exec sp_executesql @stmt=N'begin try
use msdb;
Select top 20 sj.job_id as [Job ID]
,       sj.name as [Job Name]
,       sl.name as [Owner Name]
,       (Select count(*) from sysjobschedules js1 where js1.job_id = sj.job_id ) as [Schedules Count]
,       (Select count(*) from sysjobsteps js2 where js2.job_id = sj.job_id ) as [Steps Count]
,       (Select count(*) from sysjobhistory jh1 where jh1.job_id=sj.job_id and jh1.step_id = 0 and jh1.run_status = 0 and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert( varchar, jh1.run_date) ), getdate()) < 7  ) as [Failure Count]
,       (Select avg(((run_duration/10000*3600) + ((run_duration%10000)/100*60) + (run_duration%100))+0.0) from sysjobhistory jh2 where jh2.job_id=sj.job_id and jh2.step_id = 0 and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert( varchar, jh2.run_date) ), getdate()) < 7  ) as [Average Run Duration]
,       (Select avg(retries_attempted+0.0) from sysjobhistory jh2 where jh2.job_id=sj.job_id and jh2.step_id = 0 and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert( varchar, jh2.run_date) ), getdate()) < 7  ) as [Average  Retries Attempted]
,       Count(*) as [Execution Count]
,1 as l1
from sysjobhistory jh
inner join sysjobs sj on ( jh.job_id = sj.job_id )
inner join sys.syslogins sl on ( sl.sid = sj.owner_sid )
where jh.step_id = 0 and datediff( day, convert(datetime, convert( varchar, jh.run_date) ), getdate()) < 7 
group by sj.job_id, sj.name, sl.name
order by [Average Run Duration] desc
end try
begin catch
select 1 as [Job ID],1 as [Job Name],1 as [Owner Name],1 as run_status,1 as [Schedules Count],1 as [Steps Count]
,       ERROR_NUMBER() as  [Execution Count]
,       ERROR_SEVERITY() as [Average Run Duration]
,       ERROR_STATE() as [Average  Retries Attempted]
,       ERROR_MESSAGE() as [Failure Count]
,       -100 as l1 
end catch',@params=N''
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this forum entry: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic434103-149-1.aspx

I saw a link to a download for the SQL 2005 reports `.rdl` files here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic434103-149-1.aspx

This would probably be a good place to start. Perhaps you could alter these and then schedule them through SSRS.

Comment: For your answer to be valuable over time, please include at least the main points from the referenced site.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Blog restructuring means that the posts referenced have been moved.

"Custom Reports in Management Studio"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/managingsql/custom-reports-in-management-studio

"Management Studio Reports - Part 3 - Standard Reports"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/managingsql/management-studio-reports-part-3-standard-reports

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. It's perfectly acceptable to edit the original post and add in the new links. Thanks for your contribution, I edited @gbn's post with the update